# Error send post data in C with socket

Tags: c, apache, httprequest, winsock2

I want to send post data to php script, but php never get my post data. Here my code :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[1024] , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");

    // Work well with Get Method
    // strcat(message, "GET /voleur/receiver.php?arg1=Hello HTTP/1.1\n");
    strcpy(message, "POST /voleur/receiver.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    strcat(message, "Host: 127.0.0.1:80\r\n");
    strcat(message, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    strcat(message, "Content-Length: 10\r\n");
    strcat(message, "Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n\r\n");
    strcat(message, "arg1=Hello");




    if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Data Send\n");

    //Receive a reply from the server
    if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }

    puts("Reply received\n");

    //Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    puts(server_reply);

    return 0;
}
```

This the php script :

```
<?php
   echo "POST DATA : ".json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Here the response :

```
Reply received

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 10:34:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.8
Content-Length: 14
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

POST DATA : []
```

When i try send data throught GET method thats work well, but for POST method, PHP script doesn't receive any data from client.

Comment: Two obvious mistakes: 1) The line terminator for HTTP must be `\r\n`. 2) Your first call to `strcat` should be `strcpy` since `message` does not yet contain any string to concatenate onto.

Comment: I was try with line terminator but still doesn't work, any idea again ?, please..

Comment: If you're 100% sure the problem is still there, can you update the code in the question with those two things fixed? (So I can make sure you fixed them correctly and so that other people don't give you answers that won't actually fix your issue.)

Comment: Thankyou veryyyyyy much David, thats work!. I forget to repace first strcat with strcpy.
Thankyou Very much.

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou for David Schwartz, this the right code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[1024] , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");

    // Work well with Get Method
    // strcat(message, "GET /voleur/receiver.php?arg1=Hello HTTP/1.1\n");
    strcpy(message, "POST /voleur/receiver.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    strcat(message, "Host: 127.0.0.1:80\r\n");
    strcat(message, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    strcat(message, "Content-Length: 16\r\n");
    strcat(message, "Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n\r\n");
    strcat(message, "arg1=Hello World");




    if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Data Send\n");

    //Receive a reply from the server
    if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }

    puts("Reply received\n");

    //Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    puts(server_reply);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that you changed "Hello" to "Hello World" and it started to work ?
Did I miss something ?

Comment: @staringlizard See my comment on the question. I described two bugs in his code, and he fixed them and then it worked.